# The number of binary sequences of length 300 made up of 50 ones and 250 zeros so that between Every two ones has at least one zero.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, bit-strings

I tried a scenario where the number 0 represents a red ball and the number 10 represents a blue ball. I have a collection of 200 red balls, each occupying one spot, and 50 blue balls, each occupying two spots. The objective is to distribute these 250 balls across a total of 300 places.

I feel like I'm not in the right direction at all and would appreciate some help

Comment: Look up "stars and bars"

Comment: Think of the blue balls as occupying one spot each, so that you have $250$ positions to fill.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So I actually have to spread 50 blue balls to 250 places?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, I just realized there is a subtlety I overlooked.  You only need the first $49$ blue balls to have a $0$ after the $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am going to take a different approach, I will use different colors.  Suppose we have $50$ green and $250$ yellow balls.  We wish to arrange the balls in a row so that no two of the green balls are adjacent.  First, we will set aside $49$ of the yellow balls to be used later.  That leaves $50$ green balls and $201$ yellow balls.  They can be arranged in $\binom{251}{50}$ ways.  Next, place a yellow ball to the immediate right of each of the first $49$ green balls to ensure that no two of the green balls are adjacent.  Place a $1$ on each green ball and a $0$ on each yellow ball.  The resulting binary sequence has the property that there is at least one $0$ between each two $1$s.  Thus, the number of admissible arrangements is $\binom{251}{50}$.

Answer (score 0):

- Arrange the $250$ zeroes in a row
- In the $251$ interstices (including the ends) between the zeroes, insert the $1's$ in $\binom{251}{50}$ ways